# How to fix Android studio adb error on windows 10?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, adb

When I ran any emulator, it is running but I am getting below error.

And also, debugging tools are not working related to adb.

[image: error 1]

[image: error 2]

Even the C:\Users\UReddy\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk is installed and set to path variable also.

Comment: In the AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools folder do you have an adb.exe file? If not, you might try reinstalling Android Studio with antivirus turned off.

Comment: It is already there and I removed antivirus also

Answer (score 0):

1. on your android studio at the top right corner beside the search icon you can find the SDK Manager.
2. view android SDK location (this will show you your sdk path)
3. navigate to file explorer on your system, and locate the file path, this should be found something like
   Windows=> c://Users/johndoe/AppData/local/android (you can now see the sdk.)
   Mac=>/Users/johndoe/Library/Android/sdk
4. check the platform tools folder and see if you would see anything like adb.exe (it should be missing probably because it was corrupted and your antivirus or windows defender has quarantined it)
5. close Android Studio, open the Task Manager and finish the ADB.exe process if it's running and then delete the platform tools folder
6. go back to android studio and from where you left off navigate to sdk tools (this should be right under android sdk location)
7. uncheck android sdk platform-tools and select ok. (this will uninstall the platform tools from your ide) wait till it is done and then your gradle will sync.
8. after sync is complete, go back and check the box of android sdk platform-tools (this will install a fresh one with new adb.exe) wait till it is done and sync project and then you are good to go.

If you are still having problems, you may need to [set the Project SDK](https://superuser.com/a/1561048/504449).

Comment: I tried the steps as you mentioned but still the issue persists. I have recorded those steps while applying. Can you please check it once. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_V27kKxeHw

Comment: Can please check whether this works https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19ESTnrmYJY